# Graphics libraries in 2020

Tags: python, c++, graphs, vector-graphics, pixel-graphics

What are the most widely used graphics libraries 2020?

I want to learn how to use some graphics libraries. I have written various programs in python and c++, and it seems that animating these would be a good way to learn a graphics library- so if there are any good and modern libraries for these languages that would be ideal. However, I don't mind learning a new language if there is perhaps a more widely used graphics library in some other language. The main thing is that I want to learn the most **useful** graphics library for 2020- i.e. I am not going to learn how to use the c++ graphics.h library, as it is out of date, rather I want to know which libraries are still actively being developed and used by the big companies.

Also, I am on mac, if that is relevant- I can see that Metal is one modern option, but the learning curve seems quite steep so I have so far held off from committing to it.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending software meeting specific requirements – not approaches, [languages](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185), [technologies](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/185) or [algorithms](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/185). Also, what is "best" or "most important" is quite subjective – and we don't recommend things valid only for a given time frame. Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) to get an idea what questions are fitting here.

Comment: Ok, I have reworded the question- can you have another look at it? What I want to know is basically which are the graphics libraries for 2020 in c++ and python, which can be answered by fact and citation

Comment: Thanks – but no, thanks: "most widely used" is not a valid criterium here. Have you checked the links from my previous comment?